# How do I pass a name as key in dictionary structure?

Tags: python

I am writing binary search tree for book phone. The problem is when I am trying to write the main code. I tried to use dictionary data structure but I cannot figure out how to make contact name as a key. I want to write any name and get phone number as a value.

It gave me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FastSort.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(binarySearch(phonebook, "John"))
  File "FastSort.py", line 8, in binarySearch
    if alist[midpoint] == item:
KeyError: 1
```

This is a code

```
def binarySearch(alist, item):
       first = 0
       last = len(alist)-1
       found = False

       while first<=last and not found:
           midpoint = (first + last)//2
           if alist[midpoint] == item:
               found = True
           else:
            if item < alist[midpoint]:
                  last = midpoint-1
            else:
                first = midpoint+1
                return found

phonebook = {}
phonebook["John"] = 938477566
phonebook["Jack"] = 938377264
phonebook["Jill"] = 947662781

print(binarySearch(phonebook, "John"))
print(binarySearch(phonebook, "Jack"))
```

Comment: You should be using a sorted list for binary search, not a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you need a special search function for dictionary lookups? They're already O(1).

Comment: `phonebook` has three possible keys: 'John', 'Jack', 'Jill'; when you call `alist[midpoint]`, `midpoint` is a number (in this case 1), you're calling `phonebook[1]`, which does not exist since it is not one of the three existing keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution (if `alist` as really a sorted list) was pretty close so I thought I would help you out a bit:

```
import random

def binarySearch(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1

    while first<=last:
        midpoint = (first + last)//2
        print midpoint
        if alist[midpoint][0] == item:
            return alist[midpoint]
        else:
         if item < alist[midpoint][0]:
               last = midpoint-1
         else:
             first = midpoint+1
    return False

items = []
items.append(("John", 938477566))
items.append(("Jack", 938377264))
items.append(("Jill", 947662781))

items = sorted(items)    

print(binarySearch(items, "John"))
print(binarySearch(items, "Jack"))
print(binarySearch(items, "Jill"))
```